# Session files laravel 5.1.7 Not writable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

My Session files are not writable

I make chmod -R 777 storage/framework/sessions but per each request be create a session file.

I using a 1&1 shared server with PHP 5.5.26

app.blade.php

```
<?php
    $encrypter = app('Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter');
    $encrypted_token = $encrypter->encrypt(csrf_token());
?>
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{<?php echo $encrypted_token ?>}}">
```

main.js

```
 $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content') }
    });
```

login.blade.php

```
@section('loginForm')
{!! Form::open(['route'=>'login', 'role' => 'form', 'name' => 'loginForm', 'id'=>'loginForm', 'data-toggle' => 'validator', 'class' => 'form-horizontal' ]) !!}
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label hidepola">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control" data-error="El correo de seguir esta forma ejemplo.correo@dominio.com" pattern="^[_a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Correo" required>
        <div class="help-block with-errors" ></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 control-label hidepola">Contraseña</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input data-minlength-error="Minimo son 6 caracteres" data-minlength="6" maxlength="16" class="form-control" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña" required>
      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10 col-xs-12">
      <div class="checkbox" id="ingresa">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox"> Recordarme
          <a href="{{ URL::route('recoverView') }}">¿Olvidaste tu Contraseña?</a>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      {!! Form::submit('Iniciar Sesion',['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
    </div>
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

@stop

AuthController

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $data['email'], 'password' => $data['password'], 'is_active' => 1],$request->has('remember'))) {

            return response()->json([
                'success' => [
                    'message' => 'Login User'
                ]
            ], 200);

        }
```

My repo is [here](https://github.com/kyxer/barrioosserver)
Thanks a lot

Comment: More input !!  Are they not writeable by PHP ?

Comment: I think so because, in my local environment working fine,  and I made ls -l on sesion file an output is -rw----r--

Comment: isn't it better to use APC or COOKIE driver than FILE?

Answer (score 0):

In remote server cleanup session folder and then give 777 permission to folder.
But I recommend You to change session driver to:

1. APC ('driver' => 'apc') 

   or
2. COOKIE ('driver' => 'cookie')

in config/session.php file
and enable encryption ('encrypt' => true) when using COOKIE driver

we know that session id stored in cookie, so why not to keep whole session data in cookie and encrypt it?

Comment: sorry the problem persist I changed the method for stored session but the token CSRF and Session Toke are diferent and i can't athenticate the user, I sent the token in petition ajax in header

Comment: Can You remove CSRF middleware? Is it necessary for You to use CSRF token?

Comment: if remove CSRF pass auth but not have session store between page

Comment: strange...  "I sent the token in petition ajax in header" - can You update Your answer and add the controller that does auth routine and the view that has auth form?

Answer (score 0):

I save my layout.blade.file to UTF8 without BOM with Notepad ++

I use sesion driver file.

I use [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-creates-a-new-session-after-each-request) link.